# Two Color Scales for geom_line in ggplot2

Tags: r, graphics, statistics, ggplot2

I have a chart (code to replicate will be below) that has two lines (and points) of data that need to be color coded, then three sets of confidence intervals (lines) which need to have their own color coding.

Unfortunately, ggplot sees the two calls to geom_line() and fits them all in the same scale.

[image]

Is there a way to have the central lines and dots have one scale (and legend entry) while the outer lines have a seperate scale (and legend entry)?

I've seen (complex) answers like [ggplot2: Multiple color scales or shift colors systematically on different layers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232331/ggplot2-multiple-color-scales-or-shift-colors-systematically-on-different-layer) but that relies on the old proto system which I believe has been phased out by now(?).

Thanks for any help.

Code to produce data and graphs.  Sorry for the length:

```
exShapedMayGroup <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(14730, 14730, 14730, 14731, 
14731, 14731, 14734, 14734, 14734, 14735, 14735, 14735, 14736, 
14736, 14736, 14737, 14737, 14737, 14740, 14740, 14740, 14741, 
14741, 14741, 14742, 14742, 14742, 14743, 14743, 14743, 14744, 
14744, 14744, 14745, 14745, 14745, 14746, 14746, 14746, 14748, 
14748, 14748, 14749, 14749, 14749, 14750, 14750, 14750, 14750, 
14750, 14750, 14751, 14751, 14751, 14752, 14752, 14752, 14752, 
14752, 14752, 14754, 14754, 14754, 14756, 14756, 14756, 14757, 
14757, 14757, 14758, 14758, 14758, 14758, 14758, 14758, 14759, 
14759, 14759, 14760, 14760, 14760), class = "Date"), Score = c(0.028, 
0.028, 0.028, 0.03289, 0.03289, 0.03289, 0.034512, 0.034512, 
0.034512, 0.0373496, 0.0373496, 0.0373496, 0.03201968, 0.03201968, 
0.03201968, 0.040805744, 0.040805744, 0.040805744, 0.0344045952, 
0.0344045952, 0.0344045952, 0.04017367616, 0.04017367616, 0.04017367616, 
0.035998940928, 0.035998940928, 0.035998940928, 0.0342191527424, 
0.0342191527424, 0.0342191527424, 0.09799532219392, 0.09799532219392, 
0.09799532219392, 0.122746257755136, 0.122746257755136, 0.122746257755136, 
0.0999570062041088, 0.0999570062041088, 0.0999570062041088, 0.0950656049632871, 
0.0950656049632871, 0.0950656049632871, 0.0837224839706296, 0.0837224839706296, 
0.0837224839706296, 0.00418, 0.00418, 0.00418, 0.0806379871765037, 
0.0806379871765037, 0.0806379871765037, 0.009624, 0.009624, 0.009624, 
0.0099792, 0.0099792, 0.0099792, 0.090740389741203, 0.090740389741203, 
0.090740389741203, 0.0905523117929624, 0.0905523117929624, 0.0905523117929624, 
0.0761218494343699, 0.0761218494343699, 0.0761218494343699, 0.0707874795474959, 
0.0707874795474959, 0.0707874795474959, 0.02132336, 0.02132336, 
0.02132336, 0.0636099836379967, 0.0636099836379967, 0.0636099836379967, 
0.0550479869103974, 0.0550479869103974, 0.0550479869103974, 0.0466883895283179, 
0.0466883895283179, 0.0466883895283179), Right = c("1", "2", 
"3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", 
"1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", 
"2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", 
"3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", 
"1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", 
"2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", 
"3"), .id = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", 
"0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), Lower = c(0.0452301816389807, 
0.0299531343622987, 0.0146760870856168, 0.0409430625769167, 0.0213788962381707, 
0.00181472989942479, 0.0386359600820249, 0.0167646912483872, 
-0.00510657758525054, 0.037279363974053, 0.0140514990324434, 
-0.00917636590916623, 0.0364512577706185, 0.0123952866255743, 
-0.0116606845194698, 0.0359359120595814, 0.0113645952035002, 
-0.0132067216525811, 0.0356116886483614, 0.0107161483810601, 
-0.0141793918862411, 0.035406383399575, 0.0103055378834873, -0.0147953076326005, 
0.0352758647295475, 0.0100445005434323, -0.0151868636426829, 
0.0351926859362388, 0.00987814295681498, -0.0154364000226088, 
0.035139594640892, 0.00977196036612139, -0.0155956739086492, 
0.0351056744462797, 0.00970411997689682, -0.0156974344924861, 
0.0350839892725913, 0.00966074962952, -0.0157624900135513, 0.0350701204632195, 
0.00963301201077625, -0.0158040964416669, 0.035061248392137, 
0.00961526786861143, -0.0158307126549142, NA, NA, NA, 0.0350555718896789, 
0.00960391486369513, -0.0158477421622886, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0.0350519395924259, 0.00959665026918906, -0.0158586390540477, 
0.0350496151941651, 0.00959200147266757, -0.01586561224883, 0.0350481276906492, 
0.00958902646563569, -0.0158700747593778, 0.035047175734008, 
0.00958712255235328, -0.0158729306293014, NA, NA, NA, 0.0350465665004368, 
0.00958590408521094, -0.0158747583300149, 0.0350461765986017, 
0.00958512428154069, -0.0158759280355203, 0.0350459270645606, 
0.00958462521345864, -0.0158766766376434), Upper = c(0.0757842761923446, 
0.0910613234690266, 0.106338370745709, 0.0800713952544086, 0.0996355615931546, 
0.119199727931901, 0.0823784977493004, 0.104249766582938, 0.126121035416576, 
0.0837350938572723, 0.106962958798882, 0.130190823740492, 0.0845632000607068, 
0.108619171205751, 0.132675142350795, 0.0850785457717439, 0.109649862627825, 
0.134221179483906, 0.0854027691829639, 0.110298309450265, 0.135193849717566, 
0.0856080744317504, 0.110708919947838, 0.135809765463926, 0.0857385931017778, 
0.110969957287893, 0.136201321474008, 0.0858217718950865, 0.11113631487451, 
0.136450857853934, 0.0858748631904333, 0.111242497465204, 0.136610131739975, 
0.0859087833850456, 0.111310337854428, 0.136711892323811, 0.085930468558734, 
0.111353708201805, 0.136776947844877, 0.0859443373681059, 0.111381445820549, 
0.136818554272992, 0.0859532094391883, 0.111399189962714, 0.136845170486239, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.0859588859416464, 0.11141054296763, 0.136862199993614, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0859625182388994, 0.111417807562136, 
0.136873096885373, 0.0859648426371602, 0.111422456358658, 0.136880070080155, 
0.0859663301406761, 0.11142543136569, 0.136884532590703, 0.0859672820973173, 
0.111427335278972, 0.136887388460627, NA, NA, NA, 0.0859678913308885, 
0.111428553746114, 0.13688921616134, 0.0859682812327236, 0.111429333549785, 
0.136890385866846, 0.0859685307667647, 0.111429832617867, 0.136891134468969
)), .Names = c("Date", "Score", "Right", ".id", "Lower", "Upper"
), row.names = c(NA, 81L), class = "data.frame")


ggplot(exShapedMayGroup, aes_string(x="Date", y="Score"))  + geom_line(aes_string(group=".id", colour=".id")) + 
    geom_point(aes_string(colour=".id")) + geom_line(aes_string(y="Lower", colour="Right")) + 
    geom_line(aes_string(y="Upper", colour="Right")) + scale_color_discrete(name="Limits")
```

P.S. Only using aes_string because this is called in a function which allows the user to input columns as a character.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately Hadley confirmed this is not possible. So I decided to use linetype instead (and not have anything distinguishing the points).  This made everyone happy.

```
ggplot(exShapedMayGroup, aes_string(x="Date", y="Score")) + 
geom_line(aes_string(group=".id", linetype=".id")) +  
geom_point() + 
geom_line(aes_string(y="Lower", colour="Right")) + 
geom_line(aes_string(y="Upper", colour="Right")) + 
scale_linetype_discrete(name="Group") + scale_color_discrete(name="Limits")
```

[image]

Comment: is it still not possible? I'm just wondering maybe after 7 years this was implemented? I have essentially the same problem with two calls to geom_point

Answer (score 11):

The **ggplot2** way to do this is to *not* use `geom_line` for your confidence bands. There's a geom built specifically for that: `geom_ribbon`.

```
ggplot(exShapedMayGroup, aes(x=Date, y=Score))  + 
        geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Lower,ymax = Upper,fill = Right,group = Right),alpha = 0.25) +
        geom_line(aes(group= .id, colour= .id)) + 
        geom_point(aes(colour = Right)) + 
        scale_color_discrete(name="Limits")
```

[image]

Obviously, I can't be sure that you'll be happy with how this looks, but this is generally how you approach this kind of graph in **ggplot2**. Note that I removed the `aes_string` uses in your code.

Comment: While that looks nice and is certainly a good option, I have to use lines in my plot due to client requests.

Comment: @Jared - I'd ask for a new client :)

Comment: I believe `geom_ribbon` has both edges and fill colo(u)r, so you could probably use a different colour scale (and set fill=NA or something)?

Comment: @BenBolker Sadly, `geom_ribbon` is really a filled polygon, so doing that would give you tons of vertical lines as well.

Comment: @joran Your answer is awesome, but unfortunately not what I needed for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is much simpler now, thanks to the Elio Campitelli's [`ggnewscale`](https://eliocamp.github.io/ggnewscale/) package

```r
#install.packages("ggnewscale")
library(ggnewscale)

ggplot(exShapedMayGroup, aes(x=Date, y=Score)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color=.id)) +  
  geom_point(aes(color = .id)) + 
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2") + 
  ggnewscale::new_scale_color() +
  geom_line(aes(y=Lower, colour=Right)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=Upper, colour=Right)) + 
  scale_linetype_discrete(name="Group") +
  scale_color_discrete(name="Limits")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>