# how to distinguish 4 factors in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How does one distinguish 4 different factors (not using size)? Is it possible to use hollow and solid points to distinguish a variable in ggplot2?

```
test=data.frame(x=runif(12,0,1),
     y=runif(12,0,1),
     siteloc=as.factor(c('a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b')),
     modeltype=as.factor(c('q','r','s','q','r','s','q','r','s','q','r','s')),
     mth=c('Mar','Apr','May','Mar','Apr','May','Mar','Apr','May','Mar','Apr','May'),
     yr=c(2010,2011,2010,2011,2010,2011,2010,2011,2010,2011,2010,2011))
```

where x are observations and y are modeling results and I want to compare different model versions across several factors. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I think , it very difficult visually to distinguish/compare x and y values according to 4 factors. I would  use faceting and I reduce the number of factors using `interaction` for example.

Here an example using `geom_bar`:

[image]

```
set.seed(10)
library(reshape2)
test.m <- melt(test,measure.vars=c('x','y'))
ggplot(test.m)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=interaction(yr,mth),y=value,
                 fill=variable),stat='identity',position='dodge')+
  facet_grid(modeltype~siteloc)
```

Comment: Thanks @agstudy.  The more I mess with this the more I like these bargraphs (although I flipped facet_grid(site~model.type) because the intermodel comparison is the important part). One thing, is there a way to order x-axis chronologically instead of alphabetically?

Answer (score 3):

You can use hollow and solid points, [but only with certain shapes as described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965870/fill-and-border-colour-in-geom-point-scale-colour-manual-in-ggplot).

So, that leaves you with `fill`, `colour`, `shape`, and `alpha` as your aesthetic mappings. It looks ugly, but here it is:

```
ggplot(test, aes(x, y,
                 fill=modeltype,
                 shape=siteloc,
                 colour=mth,
                 alpha=factor(yr)
                 )) + 
geom_point(size = 4) + 
scale_shape_manual(values=21:25) +
scale_alpha_manual(values=c(0.35,1))
```

Ugly, but I guess it is what you asked for. (I haven't bothered to figure out what is happening with the legend -- it obviously isn't displaying the borders right.)

[image: Ugly]

If you want to map a variable to a kind of custom aesthetic (hollow and solid), you'll have to go a little further:

```
test$fill.type<-ifelse(test$yr==2010,'other',as.character(test$mth))
cols<-c('red','green','blue')

ggplot(test, aes(x, y,
                 shape=modeltype,
                 alpha=siteloc,
                 colour=mth,
                 fill=fill.type
)) + 
  geom_point(size = 10) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values=21:25) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values=c(1,0.5)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=cols) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(cols,NA))
```

[image: Still ugly]

Still ugly, but it works. I don't know a cleaner way of mapping both the `yr` to one colour if it is 2010 and the `mth` if not; I'd be happy if someone showed me a cleaner way to do that. And now the guides (legend) is totally wrong, but you can fix that manually.

Comment: Except none of these are hollow. Hollow and filled would work well for either siteloc or year because it's dichotomous. Shape for modeltype. Ignoring year for now, I'd like red filled square to indicate apr, site a, modeltype q. red hollow square to indicate apr, site b, modeltype q. green filled circle to indicate mar, site a, modeltype r. green hollow circle: mar, b, r. green fill diamond: mar,a,s. etc. The fill color should match the border color (when filled) or i suppose be white when 'hollow'. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Dominik I updated my answer to map the variables to a different aesthetic (hollow and solid).

Answer (score 3):

I really like using `interaction` by agstudy - I would probably try this first. But if keeping things unchanged then:

4 factors could be accomodated with faceting and 2 axes. Then there are 2 metrics *x* and *y*: one option is a bubble chart with both metrics distinguishing by color or shape or both (added jitter to make shapes less overlapping):

```
testm = melt(test, id=c('siteloc', 'modeltype', 'mth', 'yr'))

# by color
ggplot(testm, aes(x=siteloc, y=modeltype, size=value, colour=variable)) +
  geom_point(shape=21, position="jitter") +
  facet_grid(mth~yr) +
  scale_size_area(max_size=40) +
  scale_shape(solid=FALSE) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: Metrics distinguished by color]

```
#by shape
testm$shape = as.factor(with(testm, ifelse(variable=='x', 21, 25)))

ggplot(testm, aes(x=siteloc, y=modeltype, size=value, shape=shape)) +
  geom_point(position="jitter") +
  facet_grid(mth~yr) +
  scale_size_area(max_size=40) +
  scale_shape(solid=FALSE) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

```
# by shape and color
ggplot(testm, aes(x=siteloc, y=modeltype, size=value, colour=variable, shape=shape)) +
  geom_point(position="jitter") +
  facet_grid(mth~yr) +
  scale_size_area(max_size=40) +
  scale_shape(solid=FALSE) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

This is attempt based on 1st comment by Dominik to show if (x,y) is above or below 1:1 line and how big is the ratio *x/y* or *y/x* - blue triangle is if x/y>1, red circle otherwise (no need in `melt` in this case):

```
test$shape = as.factor(with(test, ifelse(x/y>1, 25, 21)))
test$ratio = with(test, ifelse(x/y>1, x/y, y/x))

ggplot(test, aes(x=siteloc, y=modeltype, size=ratio, colour=shape, shape=shape)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(mth~yr) +
  scale_size_area(max_size=40) +
  scale_shape(solid=FALSE) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: I think I like this better than using `interaction` but it's rather meaningless in this context. larger/smaller is not specifically of interest, but rather above or below 1:1 line. Is there an easy transformation/stat to make the circles more meaningful?

Comment: in other words, the interest is not in (x,y) but in x/y ratio, in particular, how much it's > or < 1, correct?

Comment: yes. I think I have something that I like, I actually removed the shape because I find different sized circles easier to compare (with red=underprediction, blue=overprediction). Is there a page that lists the shape types, I didn't see it when perusing docs.ggplot2.org/current? Also, is there anything less abstract to visually compare? I find linear distance more intuitive comparing size. Or perhaps it'd be possible to increase the number of ratio circles in the legend? Thank you for all your help

Comment: @Dominik this is [one of pages with shapes](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Shapes_and_line_types/)