# ggplot: Using factors to determine colour, shape and fill (issue with fill/color)

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have the following:

```
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(
  lng    = runif(n=20, min=5,  max=10),
  lat    = runif(n=20, min=40, max=50),
  year   = rep(c("2001","2002","2003","2004"), each=5),
  season = sample(c("spring", "autumn"), 10, replace = T),
  info   = sample(c("yes","no"), 10, replace = T)
  )
```

Which can be plotted by:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=df,
             aes(x     = lng,
                 y     = lat,
                 color = year,
                 shape = season),
             size=3)
```

To produce:

[image: plot with current code]

Great. But I want a red outline on the shapes were `info == "yes"`.

The desired output would be:

[image: desired output]

**Not made using actual data, just for demonstrative purpose.** Made in powerpoint.

Admittedly it is similar to [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001993/adding-outline-color-as-point-attribute), but not quite.

I am happy to split the `df` using a `filter` if easier then two `+ geom_points()`

Many thanks

Jim

Comment: Not sure about the border,  However, you can use size = info OR You may want to use facet_wrap( ~ info) for clearer representation of data.

Comment: Hi, yes I did toy with the idea of size, but it seems like a compromise to me. thanks for you suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a quick solution (not the best), which is to use another scale, and below I use size as the scale, then use `guides()` to manually specify the shape to appear in the legend. you need to plot the bigger red shapes first and then plot over so that it looks like an outline:

```
ggplot() +
geom_point(data=subset(df,info=="yes"),
aes(x=lng,y=lat,shape = season,size=info),col="red") + 
scale_size_manual(values=3.6)+
geom_point(data=df,
             aes(x     = lng,
                 y     = lat,
                 color = year,
                 shape = season),
             size=3)+
guides(size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 1)))
```

[image]

You can change the legend for the shape by playing around with options in the guide()

Comment: thanks for you answer. Double plotting is not a bad idea at all, or plotting black point in the middle (as per previous answer - no deleted). Thank you, I wondered if there was a way to do it otherwise...

Comment: you're welcome ... the tricky thing is the legend. One way is that for the geom_point() call you specify the shapes (basically unfilled versions) directly, but takes a bit more coding

Comment: someone in SO recommended this package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gghighlight/vignettes/gghighlight.html .. you can take a quick look, maybe it's useful for what you need