# ggplot2: How to scale colours on two dimensions, categorical and continuous

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this data

```
set.seed(28100) 
my_data <- data.frame(cat = factor(sample(c('cat1','cat2'), 50, replace = T)),
                      x = sample(1:100, 50, replace = T),
                      y = sample(1:100, 50, replace = T),
                      value = sample(1:100), 50, replace = T)
```

And I want to color my observations based on two dimensions. First, I want to distinguish between the categories by colouring based on the factor variable `cat`. Second, I want to scale the colour based on the continuous variable `value`.

This doesn't give the expected result:

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(my_data, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=cat, fill=value)) +
  geom_point(size=5) +
  theme_bw()
```

Is it possible by tweaking the arguments of `ggplot()` or `geom_point()`?

Comment: You can use `alpha` : `ggplot(my_data, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=cat, alpha=value))`

Comment: or use `shape` for discrete and and `color` for continuous :`ggplot(my_data, aes(x=x, y=y, shape=cat, col=value))`

Comment: The `alpha` idea is good @HubertL

Comment: What about colouring by your factor? and sizing by value `aes(colour = cat, size = value)` and `scale_size_continuous(range = c(2,4))`. Just another idea

Comment: if you want to continue with the two colour strategy you need to assign `geom_point(shape = 21)` shapes 21:25 have a fill aes slot in them, see this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965870/fill-and-border-colour-in-geom-point-scale-colour-manual-in-ggplot