# Can geom_text in gg_tree be coded to not stagger the distance from the nodes?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtree

I have aligned some amino acid sequences in R and imported the distance matrix (dist_mat) for use in ggtree using `tree <- ape::nj(dist_mat)`. It looks something like this:

```
    node parent branch.length          x         y     label isTip      branch    angle
1     1     14   0.000000000 0.00000000  3.000000  GAS05134  TRUE 0.000000000  90.0000
2     2     13   0.000000000 0.00000000  2.000000  GAS12252  TRUE 0.000000000  60.0000
3     3     13   0.000000000 0.00000000  1.000000  GAS12271  TRUE 0.000000000  30.0000
4     4     15   0.004565217 0.02000000  4.000000  GAS06216  TRUE 0.017717391 120.0000
5     5     18   0.060110914 0.85012362  7.000000 GAS131472  TRUE 0.820068164 210.0000
6     6     19   0.000000000 0.84990179  8.000000  GAS13399  TRUE 0.849901793 240.0000
7     7     19   0.000000000 0.84990179  9.000000  GAS11282  TRUE 0.849901793 270.0000
8     8     21   0.000000000 0.92485325 11.000000  GAS03101  TRUE 0.924853253 330.0000
9     9     21   0.000000000 0.92485325 12.000000   GAS0354  TRUE 0.924853253 360.0000
10   10     20   0.000000000 0.92485325 10.000000  GAS09426  TRUE 0.924853253 300.0000
11   11     22   0.000000000 0.91032609  5.000000  14GA0305  TRUE 0.910326087 150.0000
12   12     22   0.000000000 0.91032609  6.000000  14GA0286  TRUE 0.910326087 180.0000
13   13     13   0.000000000 0.00000000  2.447917      <NA> FALSE 0.000000000  73.4375
14   14     13   0.000000000 0.00000000  4.343750      <NA> FALSE 0.000000000 130.3125
15   15     14   0.015434783 0.01543478  5.687500      <NA> FALSE 0.007717391 170.6250
16   16     15   0.454136361 0.46957114  7.375000      <NA> FALSE 0.242502963 221.2500
17   17     16   0.031992271 0.50156341  9.250000      <NA> FALSE 0.485567279 277.5000
18   18     17   0.288449292 0.79001271  7.750000      <NA> FALSE 0.645788061 232.5000
19   19     18   0.059889086 0.84990179  8.500000      <NA> FALSE 0.819957250 255.0000
20   20     17   0.423289838 0.92485325 10.750000      <NA> FALSE 0.713208334 322.5000
21   21     20   0.000000000 0.92485325 11.500000      <NA> FALSE 0.924853253 345.0000
22   22     16   0.440754944 0.91032609  5.500000      <NA> FALSE 0.689948615 165.0000
```

A basic representation in gg_tree looks like this:

```
> gg_tree <- ggtree(size=0.2,tree, layout = "circular", branch.length = "none") + geom_tiplab2(color='blue', size=3)
```

[image]

I then append some data to add aesthetics from the original data frame:

```
> gg_tree <- gg_tree %<+% DF
> head(DF, 12)
# A tibble: 12 x 4
   id        emm      tee     `50aa_HVR_peptide`                                
   <chr>     <chr>    <chr>   <chr>                                             
 1 GAS05134  emm1.0   tee1    NGDGNPREVIEDLAANNPAIQNIRLRHENKDLKARLENAMEVAGRDFKRA
 2 GAS12252  emm1.0   tee1    NGDGNPREVIEDLAANNPAIQNIRLRHENKDLKARLENAMEVAGRDFKRA
 3 GAS12271  emm1.0   tee1    NGDGNPREVIEDLAANNPAIQNIRLRHENKDLKARLENAMEVAGRDFKRA
 4 GAS06216  emm1.19  tee1    NGDGNLREVIEDLAANNPAIQNIRLRHENKDLKARLENAMEVAGRDFKRA
 5 GAS131472 emm100.0 tee28.1 RVTTRSQAQDAAGLKEKADKYEVRNHELEHNNEKLKTENSDLKTENSKLT
 6 GAS13399  emm100.5 tee28.1 RVTTRSQAQDAAGLKEKADKYEVRNHELEHNNEKLKTENSKLTSEKEELT
 7 GAS11282  emm100.5 tee28.1 RVTTRSQAQDAAGLKEKADKYEVRNHELEHNNEKLKTENSKLTSEKEELT
 8 GAS03101  emm101.0 tee14.2 ADHPSYTAAKDEVLSKFSVPGHVWAHEREKNDKLSSENEGLKAGLQEKEQ
 9 GAS0354   emm101.0 tee14.2 ADHPSYTAAKDEVLSKFSVPGHVWAHEREKNDKLSSENEGLKAGLQEKEQ
10 GAS09426  emm101.0 tee14.2 ADHPSYTAAKDEVLSKFSVPGHVWAHEREKNDKLSSENEGLKAGLQEKEQ
11 14GA0305  emm103.0 tee8    DSPRDVTSDLTTSMWKKKAEEAEAKASKFEKQLEDYKKAQKDYYEIEEKL
12 14GA0286  emm103.0 tee8    DSPRDVTSDLTTSMWKKKAEEAEAKASKFEKQLEDYKKAQKDYYEIEEKL
```

I would then like to add the information in the "tee" column as coloured text on the outside of the tree, my attempt is as follows:

```
> gg_tree + geom_text(size = 3,aes(angle=angle, color=tee, label=tee), hjust=-2)+
  theme(legend.position="right")
```

[image]

As you can see I have tried to use "hjust" to get the "geom_text" layer to not overlap with the "geom_tiplab2" layer, but the distance for each "tee" text to the tip label seems to be dramatically different.

Can anyone suggest how to get the "tee" text to run smoothly around the outside of the tree following on form the tip labels? Note: this happens with rectangular trees too, not just circular ones.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.2

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] ggtree_1.10.2       treeio_1.2.1        ggplot2_2.2.1       readxl_1.0.0       
 [5] readr_1.1.1         DECIPHER_2.6.0      RSQLite_2.0         Biostrings_2.46.0  
 [9] XVector_0.18.0      IRanges_2.12.0      S4Vectors_0.16.0    BiocGenerics_0.24.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.14     pillar_1.0.1     compiler_3.4.3   cellranger_1.1.0 plyr_1.8.4      
 [6] tools_3.4.3      zlibbioc_1.24.0  digest_0.6.13    bit_1.1-12       jsonlite_1.5    
[11] memoise_1.1.0    tibble_1.4.1     gtable_0.2.0     nlme_3.1-131     lattice_0.20-35 
[16] pkgconfig_2.0.1  rlang_0.1.6      cli_1.0.0        rstudioapi_0.7   DBI_0.7         
[21] rvcheck_0.0.9    hms_0.4.0        bit64_0.9-7      grid_3.4.3       glue_1.2.0      
[26] R6_2.2.2         purrr_0.2.4      tidyr_0.7.2      blob_1.1.0       magrittr_1.5    
[31] scales_0.5.0     assertthat_0.2.0 colorspace_1.3-2 ape_5.0          labeling_0.3    
[36] utf8_1.1.3       lazyeval_0.2.1   munsell_0.4.3    crayon_1.3.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hjust` and `vjust` don't go so well with `coord_polar` one trick to move the `geom_text` labels away from the center is too add a value to the `x` coordinate:

```
library(ggtree)
gg_tree + geom_text(size = 3, aes(angle = angle,
                                  color = tee,
                                  label = tee,
                                  x = x + 0.4), hjust = 0)+
  theme(legend.position = "right")
```

[image]

to install `gg_tree`:

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("ggtree")
```

used data:

```
> dput(DF)
structure(list(id = structure(c(5L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 11L, 12L, 8L, 
3L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("14GA0286", "14GA0305", "GAS03101", 
"GAS0354", "GAS05134", "GAS06216", "GAS09426", "GAS11282", "GAS12252", 
"GAS12271", "GAS131472", "GAS13399"), class = "factor"), emm = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("emm1.0", 
"emm1.19", "emm100.0", "emm100.5", "emm101.0", "emm103.0"), class = "factor"), 
    tee = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    4L, 4L), .Label = c("tee1", "tee14.2", "tee28.1", "tee8"), class = "factor"), 
    X.50aa_HVR_peptide. = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 
    6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("ADHPSYTAAKDEVLSKFSVPGHVWAHEREKNDKLSSENEGLKAGLQEKEQ", 
    "DSPRDVTSDLTTSMWKKKAEEAEAKASKFEKQLEDYKKAQKDYYEIEEKL", "NGDGNLREVIEDLAANNPAIQNIRLRHENKDLKARLENAMEVAGRDFKRA", 
    "NGDGNPREVIEDLAANNPAIQNIRLRHENKDLKARLENAMEVAGRDFKRA", "RVTTRSQAQDAAGLKEKADKYEVRNHELEHNNEKLKTENSDLKTENSKLT", 
    "RVTTRSQAQDAAGLKEKADKYEVRNHELEHNNEKLKTENSKLTSEKEELT"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", 
"emm", "tee", "X.50aa_HVR_peptide."), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))

> dput(tree)
structure(list(node = 1:22, parent = c(14L, 13L, 13L, 15L, 18L, 
19L, 19L, 21L, 21L, 20L, 22L, 22L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 17L, 20L, 16L), branch.length = c(0, 0, 0, 0.004565217, 
0.060110914, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.015434783, 0.454136361, 
0.031992271, 0.288449292, 0.059889086, 0.423289838, 0, 0.440754944
), x = c(0, 0, 0, 0.02, 0.85012362, 0.84990179, 0.84990179, 0.92485325, 
0.92485325, 0.92485325, 0.91032609, 0.91032609, 0, 0, 0.01543478, 
0.46957114, 0.50156341, 0.79001271, 0.84990179, 0.92485325, 0.92485325, 
0.91032609), y = c(3, 2, 1, 4, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 10, 5, 6, 2.447917, 
4.34375, 5.6875, 7.375, 9.25, 7.75, 8.5, 10.75, 11.5, 5.5), label = structure(c(6L, 
10L, 11L, 7L, 12L, 13L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("<NA>", "14GA0286", "14GA0305", 
"GAS03101", "GAS0354", "GAS05134", "GAS06216", "GAS09426", "GAS11282", 
"GAS12252", "GAS12271", "GAS131472", "GAS13399"), class = "factor"), 
    isTip = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), branch = c(0, 0, 0, 0.017717391, 
    0.820068164, 0.849901793, 0.849901793, 0.924853253, 0.924853253, 
    0.924853253, 0.910326087, 0.910326087, 0, 0, 0.007717391, 
    0.242502963, 0.485567279, 0.645788061, 0.81995725, 0.713208334, 
    0.924853253, 0.689948615), angle = c(90, 60, 30, 120, 210, 
    240, 270, 330, 360, 300, 150, 180, 73.4375, 130.3125, 170.625, 
    221.25, 277.5, 232.5, 255, 322.5, 345, 165)), .Names = c("node", 
"parent", "branch.length", "x", "y", "label", "isTip", "branch", 
"angle"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22"))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, but I do not really understand how. Incase I have to reproduce later in another context could you explain in a bit more detail how this works? If not thanks anyway, worked a charm.

Comment: Last quick question (which I can otherwise post separately) if I then add an extra aesthetics layer such as: 

gg_tree + geom_tippoint(alpha = 1,size=0.7, aes(angle=angle,color=emm)) +
  theme(legend.position="right")

I can add some coloured dots to represent the emm types, but it adds them all to the same colour palette making it hard to distinguish colours (it adds "emm" and "tee" to the same colour scale), do you perhaps know how I can ask gg_tree to use new colour palettes for the different layers?

Comment: @reubenmcg To answer the first question plot some points in `ggplot2` and use `coord_polar()`, Then experiment with the point coordinates. As for the 2nd question, ggplot supports only one color scale per plot, one can artificially add as many as one likes outside of the aes call is separate layers, but for your purpose I recommend using hollow shapes - shapes from [21 to 25](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965870/fill-and-border-colour-in-geom-point-scale-colour-manual-in-ggplot) and using the fill aesthetic. If I was not clear, add some data and explain desired output in the OP