# What is the difference between the color and fill argument in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggmap(location) +
geom_density_2d(aes(long, lat), df) +
geom_point(aes(long, lat,**color = special**),alpha = 0.5,data = df)
```

I can not see what is different when I change color to the fill, like:

```
ggmap(location) +
geom_density_2d(aes(long, lat), df) +
geom_point(aes(long, lat,**fill = special**),alpha = 0.5,data = df)
```

what is the main difference between those two arguments?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally, `fill` defines the colour with which a geom is *filled*, whereas *colour* defines the colour with which a geom is *outlined* (the shape's "stroke", to use Photoshop language).

Points *generally* only have a colour and no fill, because, y'know—they're just points. However, [point shapes 21–25 that include both a colour and a fill](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_point.html). For example:

```
library(tidyverse)
df = data_frame(x = 1:5, y = x^2)
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(
    aes(x, y, fill = x),
    shape = 21, size = 4, colour = 'red')
```

[image: A ggplot with fill mapped to an aesthetic and colour fixed.]

Here's an example with `ggmap`, where both `fill` and `colour` are set (but not mapped to aesthetics):

```
library("ggmap")

us = c(left = -125, bottom = 25.75, right = -67, top = 49)
map = get_stamenmap(us, zoom = 5, maptype = "toner-lite")
df2 = data_frame(
  x = c(-120, -110, -100, -90, -80),
  y = c(30, 35, 40, 45, 40))

ggmap(map) +
  geom_point(
    aes(x, y), data = df2,
    shape = 21, fill = 'blue', colour = 'red', size = 4)
```

[image: A ggmap with fixed colour and stroke.]

But unless you're using those special shapes, if you use a point, give it a `colour`, not a `fill` (because most points don't have one).

Comment: You explained the differences between `fill` and `color`, but it's still not clear why OP is getting the same output on using either(see the code snippets in the question). Is it that for some shapes, both can be applied without any differences in output?

Answer (score 3):

This can't be answered much better [than done so here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965870/fill-and-border-colour-in-geom-point-scale-colour-manual-in-ggplot).

The only reason I haven't marked this as duplicate as you're asking a slightly different question. They were experiencing what they thought was a bug, you are experiencing what you think is a no change.

In summary, there are several shapes you can choose for geom_point and only some of them have a fill and colour argument.

In general `fill` changes the colour within shapes, and `colour` changes the outline.