# ggraph specify both fill and colour of nodes

Tags: r, ggraph

I have seen [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66948228/ggraph-use-fill-and-color-in-geom-node-point) of how to get node fill from the aesthetic and set the colour to have a black margin around the node. But if I try to specify a fixed color **and** fill I just get black nodes.

```
ggraph(igraph::graph_from_adjacency_matrix(matrix(sample(0:1, 100, replace=TRUE, 
                                                         prob=c(0.8,0.2)), nrow=10), 
                                           mode='undirected', diag=F)) + 
  geom_edge_link(colour = "grey") + 
  geom_node_point(fill = "red", 
                  colour = "black", 
                  size = 10) + 
  theme(legend.position = 'none') +
  theme_graph(background = "white")
```

How can I specify the colour in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Default, it takes a solid shape (shape = 19) in which 'fill' would be meaningless. Specifying the shape and adjusting the stroke would help.

```
ggraph(igraph::graph_from_adjacency_matrix(matrix(sample(0:1, 100, replace=TRUE, 
                                                         prob=c(0.8,0.2)), nrow=10), 
                                           mode='undirected', diag=F)) + 
  geom_edge_link(colour = "grey") + 
  geom_node_point(fill = "red", 
                  colour = "black", 
                  size =10,
                  shape = 21, # Change the shape
                  stroke = 2) + # Specify the width of margin
  theme(legend.position = 'none') +
  theme_graph(background = "white")
```

[image]